# Extract data into DF from JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am attempting to extract data from a Json dictionary to a pandas DataFrame. However, the dictionary contains another dictionary within it. I am attaching a screenshot  for reference.

[image]

The code which I wrote for extracting the data and creating the df are as follows:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=head)
extract = response.json()
df = pd.json_normalize(extract['Result'])
```

where I am defining the url and the headers.

Running the above code returns me a df, however, it still has one column(transactions) which is in a dictionary format. I am attaching a screenshot of the df for reference.

[image]

My desired output is to have the the elements of the dictionary as separate columns, within this df.

Any help on the above will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Someone may have a better way but the below should work. It removes the `transaction` dict from `extract` and then combines it back into dictionary (using dictionary unpacking) before converting to a dataframe.
I've tested it on some test data but without the original data, cannot test fully.

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=head)
extract = response.json()
transaction = extract['Result']['transaction'] # Obtain copy of transaction dict
del extract['Result']['transaction']           # Delete transaction dict from 'extract'
extract = {**extract['Result'], **transaction} # Combine the two new dicts
df = pd.json_normalize(extract)                # Convert to dataframe
```